# What causes \psxTick to no longer work?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I am using the latest `pst-plot`. When compiling the following, I got some errors as follows.

> [image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\psset
{
    xtrigLabels,
    trigLabelBase=2,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[dx=\psPiH](0,0)(-\psPiH,-2)(\psPiTwo,2){5cm}{!}
    \psxTick[labelsep=12pt](\psPiH\space 1.5 mul){A_1}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

What causes `\psxTick` to no longer work? And how to fix it?

Comment: a problem with the option `triglabels`. will be fixed ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about bug that has been fixed.

Comment: @Werner: we might need a `bug` tag. :-)

Comment: @Werner: it is _not_ fixed in TL/MiKTeX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works with the file `pst-plot.tex` from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-plot/pst-plot.tex

[image]

Comment: no, works for both

Comment: The code with this issue: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194441/19356