# Plot the square root function using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to draw the graph the function `y=\sqrt{x}` (and label it above the graph of the function) in an x-y plane. Then I need to put a filled dot on the point (4,0) (I want to label (4,0) beneath the dot, and I also I need to put a filled dot on an arbitrary point on the graph of the function and label (x,y) above the point. I need the graph for the following problem:

Find the point (x,y) on the graph of `y=\sqrt{x}` nearest the point (4,0).

I did the following, but for some reason I couldn't even get the graph of the square root function. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$x$};

\draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};

\draw[scale=0.5,domain=0:9,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{\sqrt{\x}});


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: $x-y$ plane is a bad idea, the `-` will be rendered as a minus sign. Maybe $(x,y)$-plane?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  clip=false,
  ymin=0,
  xticklabels=\empty,
  yticklabels=\empty,
  legend pos=north west
]
\addplot+[mark=none,samples=200,unbounded coords=jump] {sqrt(x)};
\legend{$y=\sqrt{x}$}
\draw[fill] (axis cs:4,0) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[below right] {$(4,0)$};
\draw[fill] (axis cs:{4.5,sqrt(4.5)}) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[above left] {$(x,y)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need to highlight the point (4,0) on the x-axis. On the graph, you highlighted the point (4,2)

Comment: @Pat_Ho please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 13):

The cause of the error in your original code is the syntax you used to call the sqrt function:

```
({\x},{\sqrt{\x}})
```

should be replaced with

```
(\x,{sqrt(\x)})
```

Comment: well spotted :)

Answer (score 6):

An easy-to-customize template with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-eucl}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPeval\XMin{0}
\FPeval\XMax{9}
\FPeval\YMin{0}
\FPeval\YMax{4}

\FPeval\XOL{0-1/2} % of DeltaX
\FPeval\XOR{1/2} % of DeltaX
\FPeval\YOB{0-1/2} % of DeltaY
\FPeval\YOT{1/2} % of DeltaY

\FPeval\DeltaX{1}
\FPeval\DeltaY{1}

\FPeval\AxisL{XMin+DeltaX*XOL}
\FPeval\AxisR{XMax+DeltaX*XOR}
\FPeval\AxisB{YMin+DeltaY*YOB}
\FPeval\AxisT{YMax+DeltaY*YOT}

\newlength\Width\Width=10cm
\newlength\Height\Height=8cm

\newlength\llx\llx=-5pt
\newlength\urx\urx=15pt
\newlength\lly\lly=-5pt
\newlength\ury\ury=15pt


\psset
{
    llx=\llx,
    lly=\lly,
    urx=\urx,
    ury=\ury,
    labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,
    xAxisLabel=$x$,
    yAxisLabel=$y$,
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=120,
}

\def\f{sqrt(x)}


\begin{document}
\pslegend[rt]{%
    \color{NavyBlue}\rule{12pt}{1pt} & \color{NavyBlue} $y=\sqrt x$ 
}
\begin{psgraph}
    [
        dx=\DeltaX,
        dy=\DeltaY,
        Dx=\DeltaX,
        Dy=\DeltaY,
        linecolor=gray,
        tickcolor=gray,
        ticksize=-3pt 3pt,
    ]{<->}(0,0)(\AxisL,\AxisB)(\AxisR,\AxisT){\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx}{!}%{\dimexpr\Height-\ury+\lly}
    \psaxes
    [
        dx=\DeltaX,
        dy=\DeltaY,
        labels=none,
        subticks=5,
        tickwidth=.4pt,
        subtickwidth=.2pt,
        tickcolor=Red!30,
        subtickcolor=ForestGreen!30,
        xticksize=\YMin\space \YMax,
        yticksize=\XMin\space \XMax,
        subticksize=1,
    ](0,0)(\XMin,\YMin)(\XMax,\YMax)
    \psplot[linecolor=NavyBlue]{0}{\XMax}{\f}
    \pstGeonode[PointName={{(x,y)},{(4,2)},{(4,0)}},PosAngle=90]
        (*2 {\f}){temp1}
        (*4 {\f}){temp2}
        (4,0){temp3}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes

Based on Herbert's comment below,

```
PointName={{(x,y)},{(4,2)},{(4,0)}}
```

is the correct syntax of my wrong syntax

```
PointName={(x{,}y),(4{,}2),(4{,}0)}
```

Comment: The correct syntax is: `\pstGeonode[PointName={{(x,y)},{(4,2)},{(4,0)}},PosAngle=90]` otherwise TeX doesn't know which comma is part of the point name or a delimiter for the names.

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.62 ...AxisR,\AxisT){\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx}{!}
`

Answer (score 3):

And here's a simple approach with [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) to extend the set of solutions.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

% define a unit size
u := 1cm;

% define the paths and point we need

% the y = sqrt(x) curve
path f; 
f = (origin for x=0.1 step 0.1 until 6: .. (x,sqrt(x)) endfor) scaled u;

% the axes 
path xx, yy;
xx = (0,-u/2+ypart llcorner f) -- (0,u/2+ypart urcorner f);
yy = (-u/2+xpart llcorner f,0) -- (u/2+xpart urcorner f,0);

% we need a point on a circle centred at (4,0) where it touches f
% so x=y^2  and (x-4)^2+y^2=r^2 where r^2 is minimal
% hence r^2 = x^2 - 7x + 16 and d(r^2)/dx = 2x-7
% so r^2 is minimal where x=7/2
% and our point is therefore (7/2,sqrt(7/2))

z1 = (4u,0);
z2 = (3.5u,sqrt(3.5)*u);

% we can add a circle to show this
path c; 
c = fullcircle scaled 2 length (z2-z1) shifted z1;

% now draw everything in the right order
draw c withcolor .7 white;
draw f withcolor .67 red;
drawarrow xx withcolor .5 white;
drawarrow yy withcolor .5 white;

% and finally label the points
dotlabel.bot (btex $(4,0)$ etex,z1);
dotlabel.ulft(btex $(x,y)$ etex,z2);
% and the curve
label.rt(btex $y=\sqrt x$ etex, urcorner f);

endfig;
end.
```

### Notes

- As ever, the inline for-loop construct is very handy for defining function curves.
- If you define all the paths and points first and then draw them all together at the end, then it's a bit easier to get them drawn in the right order
- Once you've defined a path, you can use `urcorner`, `llcorner`, etc to refer to its bounding box.  I've used this feature here to position the label for the function curve and to make axes that fit automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$f(x)$, width=12cm]
\addplot [blue, line width = 1, smooth, domain=-2:2] {sqrt(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[thick,major tick length=3mm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-1,xmax=10.5,ymin=-5.5,ymax=5.5,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    axis line style={Triangle-Triangle},
    tick label style={black, ultra thick},
    major tick style = {thick, black},
    xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
   ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south}
    ]
    \addplot[ultra thick,red,samples=1000,domain=0:9,-Triangle]{sqrt(x)};
    \addplot[ultra thick,red,samples=1000,domain=0:9,-Triangle]{-sqrt(x)};
 \end{axis}
 
 \end{tikzpicture}
'''
```